# android studio increasing heap size not working on 2.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

When i changed to bin/studio.vmoptions then the the heap size of android studio not increasing. `studio.vmoptions` file is:

```
#
# *DO NOT* modify this file directly. If there is a value that you would like to override,
# please add it to your user specific configuration file.
#
# See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/configuration
#
-Xms256m
-Xmx4096m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops
```

but the heap size is still 676mb. How can i fix it?

Comment: if you add this as an answer i will accept :) Thank you! @MisterSmith

Comment: I posted a proper answer. Your welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android Studio, press the Help menu and then select "Edit custom VM options". This should open the correct file.

Notice that in my case this is indeed the correct file but still has the `*DO NOT* modify this file directly` comment. So I just ignored it.